# Online CAD resources for designing folding linkages?

Tags: cad, linkage

I'm trying to design a space-saving, wall-mounted, fold-away workbench that has an auxiliary platform that folds out. The fold-away linkage to support the aux platform when it's folded out is taxing my brain something fierce! Can anyone recommend an online CAD resource where I could model this and play with linkage designs?

[image: folded out]

[image: folded away/down]

Comment: since it seems to be a sketchup design, you could add Msphysics by Anton Synytsia, it allows to play inside sketchup using various joints such as hinges servos motors and sliders